# 'wp' is not recognized, but wp-cli works fine on Windows 10

Tags: wordpress, windows, command-prompt, wp-cli

I've installed wp-cli and expect to have the 'wp' command working. I have done this installation process on a near-identical machine just fine. When I enter 'wp' into Command Prompt (Admin), I get 'wp' is not a recognized as an internal or external command. I have PATH variables set to c:\wp-cli and c:\xampp\php for Admin and the System Variables. I can't seem to run "npm run setup" until this happens, so I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed. Make sure to name you wp-cli.bat file wp.bat instead. My other Windows machine was more discerning, apparently.